# Relational delete constrain custom message yii2?

Tags: yii2

Delete button not working for relational data in yii2. Because its has child data. Now i want to show custom message.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyVLZ.png)

Comment: [
'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
'visible'=>true,
'header'=>'Actions',
'template' =>(\Yii::$app->session->get('userType')==\common\models\UsefulModel::TYPE_DOS)?'{view}':(\Yii::$app->session->get('userType')==\common\models\UsefulModel::TYPE_MARITIME)?'{view}{update}':'{view}{update}{delete}',
],

Answer (score 0):

If the deletion is throwing an exception you can catch it and add an error to the model by using [addError](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#addError()-detail) function

Comment: added the following code after you've being ActiveForm`code`
echo $form->errorSummary($model);